# unity webgl audio in mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, mobile, amazon-s3, unity-webgl

I have Unity WebGL games on Amazon S3 and I want to embed them in an iframe so they are in my angular web app.

The problem I have is that when using them in mobi
le, they do not reproduce sound. The warning that goes out says:

> An AudioContext in a cross origin iframe must be created or resumed from a user gesture to enable audio output.

How can I do to enable the sound? The problem is that being a Unity application I do not have functions like play() or things like that. The user could touch the screen to enable audio? How?